# How to solve GraphQL error when no markdown file is present in Gatsby?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, gatsby

I have this query on my Gatsby site.

```
export const query = graphql`
  query MyBlogs {
    allMarkdownRemark(sort: { fields: frontmatter___date, order: DESC }) {
      edges {
        node {
          id
          fields {
            slug
          }
          frontmatter {
            date
            title
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
`;
```

Everything works fine when at least one markdown file is present in the blogs folder. As soon as I delete all the markdown files it gives me an error.
I want to know what condition can be put in the code to avoid the error when the page loads.